# How to connect two sql queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to connect two queries referring to the same table. I want to know how many fruits I got in the time range and how many of them were not fresh.

Query 1

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM fruits
WHERE date>='2017-04-01' AND date<='2017-04-30'
```

Query 2

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM fruits
WHERE fresh='no'
```

Comment: The number that is not fresh **in the time range**? Or in general?

Comment: That in the time range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression (NB: I am interpreting the "of them" in the question to be referring to fruits in the time range not fruits in general if you want fruits in general remove the where clause and move the predicate into another similar case expression)

```
SELECT COUNT(id), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN fresh = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM fruits
WHERE date>='2017-04-01' AND date<='2017-04-30'
```

Comment: No need to use a case `fresh = 'no'` is sufficient afaik.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that works in MySQL but is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM fruits
WHERE date >= '2017-04-01' AND date <= '2017-04-30' AND fresh = 'no';
```

In both queries 1 and 2, you want the same columns and just want to get the intersection of the two, so just add to the WHERE clause with an "AND".

Comment: This would sum only all bad fruits within the time range. I'm pretty sure Wiskoza want the total amount of fruits within the time range, but also how many of them were not fresh. Your answer is missing the total amount.

Comment: Sorry, i misinterpreted the question